# How to add a button to a custom table that opens a form in a new tab and automatically fills out with data from that table

Tags: forms

I have a custom module where I create a table from some data. In one of the columns I need to have a button that when clicked will open a new tab and show the user a form and a submit button and some of the form fields are pre-filled with data from the table (data from the same row).

I know how to add a button but I don't know how to pass the data to the form.

Also, for the button I'm using the following code and maybe this is already wrong:

```
$new_button = '<a href="/examples/form-example" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">New form</a>';
```

Note: the data is not in the drupal database. The table is made on the fly using REST.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Prepopulate](https://www.drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module can pass value to form with query parameter.

Simple example:

```html
<a href="/node/add/content?edit[title]=This is the title" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">New form</a>';
```

More examples can be found on its [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/228167).

If you find problems, please check this [issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2679839), some known bug has been introduced from 7.x-2.1 version. You may need to patch it.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy Ko but this is also valid for my case where the table has data not from drupal database?

Comment: No worry about that. What you want is to pass the value to form, right? The value is passed directly on the query parameter. It does not involve any database manipulation.